# Create a product-specific promo code

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible (likely through an extension) to create a promo code that only applies to a specific product? We would like to give a discount on a single product, but the discount, if applied to the entire cart, could render some items in the store completely free.

Has anyone done anything like this? If so, can you give us a sense of the logic/approach for the extension?

Thanks!

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Store 2. You can create [discounts](https://exp-resso.com/docs/control_panel_discounts.html) with promo codes, which only apply to individual products or product categories.